# Capture signal parameter in qml

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I have a QObject based python class as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal

class Validator(QObject):
    authFailed = pyqtSignal(str, arguments=['value'])

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Validator, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtslot
    def test(self):
        self.authFailed.emit("Failed")
```

On the qml side, I can listen to this signal as:

```
Validator {
    onAuthFailed: {                
    }   

    id: validator
}
```

However, I am not sure how I can capture the `str`parameter that is also emitted from the signal (The `Failed` message). When I try something like: `onAuthFailed(msg)` signature, this fails to compile.

Comment: I don't know the solution about your problem and I am just here to tell you that Python is not getting compiled but interpreted. Hence you can have an interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about PyQt...

Usually, in QML you can access the signal parameters just by using their name.

According to this:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal

the String you pass in the `arguments=['value']`-list is the name, that is used to expose the parameter to QML.
So I am pretty sure, you can just use a variable `value` in the handler in QML.

Try:

```
onAuthFailed: console.log('auth Failed: ', value)
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Auto injection of parameters is deprecated now, so here is a new answer.
At this time it still works, but I believe this is the current recommended method:

```
onAuthFailed: myString => {
  console.log('auth Failed: ', myString);
}
```

For some completeness, here is another method:
Automatching of names also still works, but is also deprecated.

```
Validator {
  function onAuthFailed(myString) {
    console.log('auth Failed: ', myString);
  }
}
```